# CUDAFunctionload error

Tags: cudalink

I am trying to get `CUDAFunctionLoad` to work with *Mathematica 9.0*.
I installed the latest clang and the *Nvidia Tools 6.0*.
but I keep getting the error message:

> ```
> CUDAFunctionLoad::cmperr: "-- Message text not found -- 
>                              "clang: error: unsupported option -dumpspecs" "
> ```

I note that others have the same problem.  i asked *NVIDIA* and *Wolfram Reaserch* for help
and they have not come up with any solution so far, although they suspect the problem is that clang in latest version is not compatible with *Mathematica 9.0*.

Any help, insights or leads would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am using Mavericks on a new iMac

Comment: Please provide all the commands that you used to load `CudaLink`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following, so you update CudaLink in the process:

```
     Needs["CUDALink`"]
     CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]
     CUDAQ[] (* This might take long *)
     CUDAInformation[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried the update to no avail.

Comment: I have a copy of the full nb with lists of detail and will try to upload it. Thanks Frank